# Run jQuery code once jQuery loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery loaded before the closing  tag on my page.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The majority of my js is loaded below this in

```
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which works well.
There is some ad code that I need to run in the head tag.
This works fine usually however I want to add a responsive exception.
eg

```
    var mob = 0;
    if(jQuery(window).width() < 727)  {
        mob = 1;
    }
    if(mob)  {console.log('run special mob related code');}
    else {console.log('run special desktop related code');}
```

Because my code is in the  I get the error ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.
Is there a way around this?
The ad code doesn't run unless it is in the head, but I can't really move the jquery into the head as I have this on multiple sites and may affect how other plugins run?

Comment: You cannot use `jQuery` var or `$` unless you load jQuery library.. If you can't load it.. then don't use the jQuery var there..

Comment: You can't run jquery code before the script tag that includes it on a given page.

Comment: Did yoy try encasing that piece of code in `DOM ready handler`

Comment: I think this link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087206/how-do-i-tell-jquery-to-run-a-function-on-one-specific-web-page-only

Comment: How complicated is the code you wan't to run? Maybe you can just use plain js for that (of course you can always use plain js) ,did that for a splash screen for the same reason although I've used jQuery for the rest of the project.

Comment: _"but I can't really move the jquery into the head as I have this on multiple sites and may affect how other plugins run"_ - It shouldn't actually break your other sites/pages if you move jquery.js to the head, except perhaps if you're trying to mix multiple version of jQuery on the same page. As long as you always include jquery.js somewhere above any scripts that use it these other scripts can still be included just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use something like this:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 727) {
mob = 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was after thanks.  I wanted to do it in plain js but wasn't able to find anything about the docuemnt.width. Thanks!

Comment: EDITED MY COMMENT: You're more than welcome, @ak85. Also, just food for thought: what happens if a non-mobile user opens the page in a browser window resized to below 727, and then expands it to full width?

Comment: I am not sure it is a major issue though because I tihnk it will not affect to many users, however it is a good point, if I was using jQuery I would look at .resize(), do you know of an equivalent in js?

Comment: In many cases reverting to plain JavaScript is simpler. Check out this thorough but easy to read book: http://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1375884901&sr=1-1&keywords=professional+javascript+for+web+developers

Answer (score 1):

Early in your code, you could define a `jQuery` property on the `window` object, which will run your code that requires jQuery when it is reassigned by the actual jQuery object.

```
(function(){
  var _jQuery;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'jQuery', {
    get: function() { return _jQuery; },
    set: function($) {
      _jQuery = $;

      // put code or call to function that uses jQuery here

    }
  });
})();
```